# Retrieve data for a time interval from a DATETIME Column MySQL /PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im pulling information from a database and ive got the query working fine except i'd like to only select conent from a certain date range. Each row has a field with the created date stored as a DATETIME field. What is the basic syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fields
  FROM table
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
```

Dates in MySQL are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so the actual query would look like:

```
SELECT fields
  FROM table
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-10-01' AND '2010-09-25'
```

Comment: Is this formatting style "OMG Ponies" invention or some common convention? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I like how it makes it easier to visualize what you are doing. Yes, I believe I started doing it after seeing one of OMG Ponies' posts.

Comment: the field is a DATETIME field which i believe stores the date as a timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS but i think the basic syntax will work regardless

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE `date_field` BETWEEN '2010-09-21 12:13:14' AND '2010-09-28 12:13:14'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

```
select * from table where datetime between DATE1 and DATE2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DateTime
BETWEEN time1 AND time2
```